# '@usename' autocomplete causes it to be reset to 'null' on escape

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

- Fill in your comment, starting with `@username`
- Select all text, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
- The autocomplete pops up again.
- Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> wil cause the username to be set to `null`

Actually, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will *always* cause the text `null` to appear, but it's happened to me a few times in this particular sequence of events.

This *only* seems to happen after you've clicked on an auto-complete username at least once.

Error in my console:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'c' to object

Error thrown at line 235, column 368 in i(c) in http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=07def1e83957:
    c=d.start+c.length;
called from line 236, column 94 in d(d) in http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=07def1e83957:
    i(e)
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 3, column 7717 in <anonymous function: dispatch>(c) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:
    c.data=r.data,c.handleObj=r,n=((f.event.special[r.origType]||{}).handle||r.handler).apply(p.elem,g),n!==b&&(c.result=n,n===!1&&(c.preventDefault(),c.stopPropagation()))
called from line 3, column 482 in <anonymous function: i>(a) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:
    return typeof f!="undefined"&&(!a||f.event.triggered!==a.type)?f.event.dispatch.apply(i.elem,arguments):b
```

I only tested this in Opera 12.16.

Comment: `This problems disappears when I disable Ghostery` - so, the bug is with Ghostery?

Comment: @Oded I was mistaken, I tested it again (removed the entire extension) and the problem still occurs. It *only* happens when you after you clicked on an auto-complete username at least once, I probably got confused there in my testing.

Comment: Could you update the question with these details?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce in current opera (19) and other browsers.

Please use a **current** browser when reporting such bugs.

---

Could not reproduce on Opera 12.16 on Linux Mint 16.

Comment: Opera 12 is still supported by Opera, and the most recent versions on some platforms (ie. Linux, FreeBSD). Whether SO supports it, is a different question of course...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - fair enough. I didn't see it was the most current Linux one. Will fire up a VM and try to repro.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this in Chrome 33.0.1750.91 beta. Pressing escape does nothing.

Also, the dropdown only reappears after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> if the username is the first word in the comment. It doesn't reappear, for example, with "Blah blah @Oded blah."